# Joomla 1.5 - how to create a table in a component's view's template?

Tags: html, templates, joomla, joomla1.5

I'm trying to create a Joomla component that displays the contents of a database table as a table on-screen. In the `com_<name>/views/<name>/view.html.php` file, what is the best way to create an HTML table that looks like a standard Joomla table? Do I create the HTML table manually and decorate it with some CSS classes, or is there a standard Joomla class/function available to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask yourself, do you need to use PHP to generate it? If Joomla has a method that does, it doesn't mean you need to use it. Save the PHP cycles for more important things.

If you're not doing anything special other than creating a table then that's my answer, otherwise provide me with a bit more information and I'll expand on it for you.

**Update**

Styling the table depends on the theme you're using. They should look the same if the CSS was done correctly. If not, find another page where a table is being used and take a look at the source code to see what classes or ids it has applied.

Comment: Thanks Pixel - what I'm trying to do is show a table to the user listing a set of serial numbers he has purchased. I want this table to appear like other tables in Joomla, not like a custom-formatted one. Cheers!